# How to print the text of a parent node and first two children

Tags: xslt, xpath

My XML is:

```
<content>
  <p>The <organization>Committee on Civil Liberties</organization> calls on the <organization>Committee on Foreign Affairs</organization>, as the committee responsible:
    <mod>
      <quotedStructure>
        <recital id="_900411">
                <num>A.</num>
                <p>Whereas the progressive development ...</p>
            </recital>
            <recital id="_900412">
                <num>B.</num>
                <p>Whereas Article ...</p>
            </recital>
            <recital id="_900413">
                <num>C.</num>
                <p>Whereas, while Member States ...</p>
            </recital>
        </quotedStructure>
    </mod>
</p>
```

My expected output is:

> The Committee on Civil Liberties calls on the Committee on Foreign Affairs, as the committee responsible:
>
> A.    Whereas the progressive development ....
>
> B.    Whereas Article ...
>
> C.    Whereas, while Member States ...

My XSLT is:

```
<xsl:template match="content/p">
 <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="content//recital">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="content//recital/num">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="content//recital/p">
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
 </xsl:template>
```

My Current Output is:

> The  calls on the , as the committee responsible:
>
> A.    Whereas the progressive development ...
>
> B.    Whereas Article ...
>
> C.    Whereas, while Member States ...

Note: I am missing the text inside `<organization>` child nodes of the parent `<p>` node.
Please let me know the XPath and XSLT to get the expected output.

Comment: Please show at least a firs try. And add your desired output - not as image.

Comment: Can you show a complete XSLT that demonstrates the problem, because the child nodes `organization` would actually be picked up by XSLT's default templates as it stands. (See http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQgg for example). Thanks!

Comment: Your XML is not well formed. Please correct that if you expect an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using this (fixed) XML file

```
<content>
    <p>The <organization>Committee on Civil Liberties</organization> calls on the <organization>Committee on Foreign Affairs</organization>, as the committee responsible:
        <mod >
            <quotedStructure>
                <recital id="_900411">
                    <num>A.</num>
                    <p>Whereas the progressive development ...</p>
                </recital>
                <recital id="_900412">
                    <num>B.</num>
                    <p>Whereas Article ...</p>
                </recital>
                <recital id="_900413">
                    <num>C.</num>
                    <p>Whereas, while Member States ...</p>
                </recital>
            </quotedStructure>
        </mod>
    </p>
</content>
```

and this XSLT file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="p" />

  <xsl:template match="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p/text()">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="mod/quotedStructure">
    <xsl:for-each select="recital">
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(num/text(),' ')" />
      <xsl:value-of select="p/text()" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result looks like this:

```
The Committee on Civil Liberties calls on the Committee on Foreign Affairs, as the committee responsible:


A. Whereas the progressive development ...
B. Whereas Article ...
C. Whereas, while Member States ...
```